# Docker mount non-empty container folder to host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am running some containers, defined by a docker-compose file and the containers are already used in production.

I found out that one of the containers (odoo) is using a data directory where it places some process-related files which are important and should be saved.

Unfortunately, I forgot to use a volume for the data to make it persistent and want to do it now.

I tried to edit the `docker-compose.yml` file and define a volume in the odoo service like:

```
volumes:
  - odoo_web_data:/var/lib/odoo
```

and run

```
docker-compose up -d
```

to recreate the container.

This would work if the container were initially created, however, all I am getting now is a warning:

> WARNING: Service "odoo" is using volume "/var/lib/odoo" from the previous container. Host mapping "user_odoo_customer_web_data" has no effect. Remove the existing containers (with `docker-compose rm odoo-customer`) to use the host volume mapping.

I guess this means that it cannot be mounted, due to the folder being non-empty and linked to the previous instance of the container.

How can I persistently mount a folder from a running container on the host?

Comment: If you/someone has access to the host, data can be copied to host directory from the live container and then mount the host folder onto the new container.

Comment: that is the naive solution I want to avoid. Is there not a more convenient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could try is to first backup all the files from `/var/lib/odoo` over to your host computer:

i.e.

```
docker run --rm -v c:\migrate:/backup alpine tar -cjf /backup/my_data.tar.bz2 -C /var/lib/odoo ./
```

then import that `tar.bz2` into the `odoo_web_data` volume you created:

```
docker run --rm -v odoo_web_data:/volume -v c:\migrate:/backup alpine tar -C /volume/ -xjf /backup/my_data.tar.bz2
```

Add this to the bottom of your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  odoo_web_data:
    external: true
```

Then go ahead and start the container again using the `docker-compose up -d` with the volume mount you have in your code already.

At that point you should have all the previous `/var/lib/odoo` data in your new named volume, and the container will be using (and storing) it from that volume.

Comment: Could you please explain why you are using the two docker run commands?  I am not sure what they are accomplishing in detail.

Comment: @wigglepee they just fire up a small alpine linux container to do the backup/restore operations. You can delete it's alpine image once you're all done.